# JQuery click() not working

Tags: jquery, click

This is the strangest thing :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".selector" ).first().css( "background-color", "red" ); // This works
    $( ".selector" ).first().click();                          // This doesn't

    $( ".selector" ).click(function(e) {

        alert("plop");

    });
});
```

Of course, when I click on a `.selector` I do see the alert... What gives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may facepalm fairly massively after this, but you're calling the click event BEFORE you're adding the click handler. Your code says this:

`Click on the first .selector`

`If any .selectors get clicked on from now on, do this function`

If you move the `click` handler above the `.click()` call, it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the order you are doing things:

```
//click the first .selector:
$( ".selector" ).first().click();                          
//from now on, when .selector is clicked, fire an alert
$( ".selector" ).click(function(e) {
    alert("plop");
});
```

If you just do:

```
//from now on, when .selector is clicked, fire an alert
$( ".selector" ).click(function(e) {
    alert("plop");
});
//click the first .selector:
$( ".selector" ).first().click();
```

It should work

Comment: haha, get out of my head, @dave! :) Upvoted because I think this answer with the code examples is slightly better than mine.